# How to implement robust thread monitoring in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 2 tasks running parallelly and here is the task information. 
Task 1 - Launch and run application
Task 2 - Monitor the application run duration. If it exceeds 30 mins, issue a stop command of task 1 application and restart both task.

Task 1 application bit heavy and memory leak prone during longer runs.

I am requesting, how can we implement robust threading solution for this situation.

```
    using QuickTest;
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TaskParallelExample
     {
     internal class Program
      {
       private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Parallel.Invoke(RunApplication, MonitorApplication);
    }

    private static void RunApplication()
    {
        Application uftInstance = new Application();
        uftInstance.Launch();
        QuickTest.Test uftTestInstance = uftInstance.Test;
        uftInstance.Open(@"C:\Tasks\Test1");
        uftInstance.Test.Run(); // It will may run more then 30 mins or less then also. It it exceeds 30 mins which is calculated from Monitor Application.
    }

    private static void MonitorApplication()
    {
        Application uftInstance = new Application();
        try
        {
            DateTime uftTestRunMonitor = DateTime.Now;
            int runningTime = (DateTime.Now - uftTestRunMonitor).Minutes;
            while (runningTime <= 30)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                runningTime = (DateTime.Now - uftTestRunMonitor).Minutes;
                if (!uftInstance.Test.IsRunning)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //To-do
        }
        finally
        {
            if (uftInstance.Test.IsRunning)
            {
                //Assume it is still running and it is more then 30 mins
                uftInstance.Test.Stop();
                uftInstance.Test.Close();
                uftInstance.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: I would use a cancel token. Task 2 can set `token.Cancel();` and Task 1 is checking whether `if (token.IsCancelled)` Something like this.

Comment: Thanks. But i can't validate Task 2 status since Task 1 application will be running state and will come out when it is over.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a `CancellationTokenSource` with timeout set to 30 mins?

```
var stopAfter30Mins = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

Then you would pass that to your worker method:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => worker(stopAfter30Mins.Token), stopAfter30Mins.Token);

...

static void worker(CancellationToken cancellation)
{
    while (true)  // Or until work completed.
    {
        cancellation.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulate work.
    }
}
```

Note that if the worker task cannot periodically check the cancellation status, there is NO *robust* way to handle task timeout.

Comment: Exactly you pointed out. task 1 application will be in running state and will not come out until run is over. Can i use Parallel.Task and monitor Task 2 with timer. If it reached 30 mins, issue a stop command of task 1 application.

Comment: @Ram What do you mean by "issue a stop command"? A `CancellationTokenSource` does "issue a stop command" (which is its entire raison d'être). The only way to non-cooperatively stop a thread is via `Thread.Abort()` which is very much NOT robust (we treat any use of `Thread.Abort()` as a bug).

Comment: I meant, not to stop the thread, instead invoke "stop command" of task 1 application.

Answer (score 1):

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task do the job

```
   CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
            Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
               {
                   token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                   // Body of for loop.
               }
           }, token);

            //Do sometohing else 
            //if cancel needed
            cts.Cancel();
```